# My html form automatically passing all field data in url

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I have created a simple html form but I have encountered a weird problem which I have never seen before. When I click on submit then all of the data is directly passing to the URL bar. I don't know what is wrong with this can anyone help?

Form:

```
      <form id="form-data">
          Name<br><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""><br><br>
          Age<br><input type="number" name="number" id="age" value=""><br><br>
          Gender<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Fe-male<br><br>
    
          <select name="country">
            <option value="Kashmir">Kashmir</option>
            <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
            <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
            <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
          </select><br>
          <br><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save">
      </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the form uses get method therefore it displays the form values in the url. change the method to post to avoid this

```
method="post"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<body>
  <form id="form-data" method="post">
      Name<br><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""><br><br>
      Age<br><input type="number" name="number" id="age" value=""><br><br>
      Gender<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Fe-male<br><br>

      <select name="country">
        <option value="Kashmir">Kashmir</option>
        <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
        <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
        <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
      </select><br>
      <br><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add method attribute to your form tag like this:

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you don't send the data somewhere, it gets passed as URL parameters to the current page:
[From MDN Web Docs:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

> The action attribute defines where the data gets sent. Its value must
> be a valid relative or absolute URL. If this attribute isn't provided,
> the data will be sent to the URL of the page containing the form — the
> current page.